# reading fortran binary file in c++

Tags: c++, file, binary, fortran

The problem of reading (with c++ program) binary file generated by fortran code has been asked many times and the satisfactory description of conventions in fortran records has been given (e.g. http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/dataformats/fortran/ )

However when I try to implement c++ program, keeping in mind fortran conventions it still does not work. Here I assume we that the binary file "test.bin" contains 1 integer and is written in binary format by fortran routines.
Here is how I try to read it in c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  ifstream file;
  file.open("test.bin", ios::in|ios::binary);
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    int ival;
    file >> ival >> ival;  cout<< ival<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Here the double >>ival construction first reads the header of the fortran record (which contains the size of the record in bytes) and the second >>ival supposed to extract the value. The integer written in file is 8, but the program outputs 0, so it does not read the data properly.

Here is a content of the binary file:
    ^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^H^@^@^@^D^@^@^@^@^@^@^@

So my question - what am I doing wrong?

Here is what hex editor shows:

```
0000000: 0400 0000 0000 0000 0800 0000 0400 0000  ................
0000010: 0000 0000 0a                             .....
```

Any idea what that means?

Comment: HEX!  Outputting the bytes as characters is not helping any.

Comment: figure out if it is big endian or little endian.  Intel is little endian.  `^@ = 0, ^D = 4, ^H = 8`.  Looks to me like little endian, record size is 4, value is 8.  I do not know what the last 8 bytes are.

Comment: The `>>` operator reads textual data (i.e., it tries to parse an decimal representation of an integer). Use the `read` member function to read binary data.

Comment: Well, the second integer, assuming 32-bit little-endian, is actually 0, next 8 and then 4.  If the first integer written in the file is actually 8, it may be that the size header is a 64-bit integer - quite reasonable with large disk files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`operator>>` is the *formatted* input operator. It is used to read text files, converting the textual representation to binary.

You should be reading using *unformatted* input operations. Try this:

```
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ival), sizeof ival);
```

Of course, after you read it, you may need to byte swap for correct endian representation.

Comment: I also tried another method: I first read entire content of the file in char buffer memoryblock, then i copy some elements of the memorymlock into temporary buffer  buff (e.g. 4 elements) and the try: ival = atoi(buff). This still gives me 0, although I do not
 use >> operator  (read function for binary input). Why is it not working?

Comment: It isn't working because you use `atoi` -- a function which converts text to binary. You don't have text, you already have binary. There is no need to convert it. If you have read the file into a buffer, try this: `memcpy((void*)&ival, &memoryblock[0], sizeof ival)`.

Answer (score 1):

Open it in a hex editor and dig out the structure.  Is the header size 16, 32, 64 or 128 bits and which end up is it?

Hex editor..

Comment: As I understand, the header should be 4 bytes (see the reference/link I give), that is why I use first >>ival operation. Also: the file is in Linux - is there any Linux hex editors? Is it possible to copy that file to windows and use hex editor for windows?

Comment: In many Linux distributions, you can display a file in hex like this: `od -txCz filename`.